# Hibernate Criteria Query not working with date

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

The following line of code works perfectly when tested with **string**

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", "John"));
```

However when i test it with **Date** it returns error
This is line of code that returns error

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(currentDate,dd));
```

This is how i am getting currentDate

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String currentDate=dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

I printed **currentDate** and **dd** and following is output in console along with the error

Current Date:2014-02-17
 dd:2014-02-16

JKInsrException:->could not resolve property: 2014-02-17 of: com.java.JKInsr.Contact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restrictions.eq() takes a property-name as first argument, not a value or object.

You should do it like this:

```
Restrictions.eq("myDate", dd)
```

Make sure your Contact class has the myDate-Attribute.

Comment: Thanks a lot...It worked for me. I messed up with the syntax.